# Trying to understand a property of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have to solve the following problem:

> Find a general formula for sequence: 
>   $a_1 = 1$ $a_{n+1}= a_n + (n+1)^3,  \forall n \in \Bbb N$

Using this:

> $\sum_{i=1}^n (a_{i+1} - a_i) = a_{n+1} - a_1$

I don't understand how to replace each term in order to leave $a_n$ by itself.

I can replace $a_{n+1}$ in right side of the equality and $a_1$ with 1, but I can't see further than that. I also have expanded the sum but I obviously ended up with that right side of the equation.

Any explanations?? Thanks!

Comment: It is simply put, a true statement for all $a_n$ and is called a telescoping sum

Comment: Yes, but how can I derive the general formula for a sequence using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a_{i+1} - a_i)$ is nothing but $(i+1)^3$. So the $LHS$ becomes
$$\sum_{i=1}^n {(i+1)^3}$$ and the $RHS$ is $a_{n+1} - 1$. So you can find $a_{n+1}$(and hence $a_n$) provided you find the summation.
Can you do that?

Comment: Thanks, yes I can find the summation like that. I still don't understand why $(a_{i+1} - a_i)$ is $(i+1)^3$ though...

Comment: Because $a_{n+1}= a_n + (n+1)^3,  \forall n \in \Bbb N$ and all $i$'s in the summation range are natural numbers

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$a_{n+1}=a_n+(n+1)^3$$

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=(n+1)^3$$

---

$$\sum_{i=1}^ni^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}4$$